# virtualenv isolated app somehow finds global django installation instead of local one

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

1. I have globally installed django v1.8 on (ubuntu + apache + mod_wsgi)
2. I have a virtualenv *'myenv'* with --no-site-packages (which means it is isolated from global packages) with django 1.9 installed inside

here is my app's apache config

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/djp/myapp:/root/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com python-path=/var/djp/myapp:/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/djp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp/myapp_error.log
    LogLevel info

</VirtualHost>
```

if then i switch to myenv and check version in python i get

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 9, 7, 'final', 0)
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path 
*the path is ok*
```

But if i open up webpage of my app i see the following

```
Django Version: 1.8.3

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/var/djp/myapp', # - ok
 '/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages', # - ok
 '/usr/lib/python2.7', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', # - not ok (global)
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

I just dont get it, why it executes django 1.8 first? My local site-packages should be found first. My first thought was, that python just couldn't find django 1.9 in myenv. But i can easily import it from python shell as shown above!

Here is the output of pip freeze in myenv:

```
Django==1.9.7
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
djangorestframework==3.3.3
psycopg2==2.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Everything is on it's place. I have no idea what happens. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com python-home=/root/.virtualenvs/myenv python-path=/var/djp/myapp
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/djp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp/myapp_error.log
    LogLevel info

</VirtualHost>
```

That is, turn off interpreter initialisation in embedded mode processes and then use `python-home` option to say where virtual environment is.

The remaining question is whether you are using a non system Python installation. If you are and mod_wsgi was actually compiled for system Python and not your separate one, more work is needed.

A further issue may also be that `/root` directories are not actually readable to Apache user.

Comment: Your second guess was right, Apache didn't have rights to read /root directory. I moved my virtualenvs to /var/.virtualenvs and now everything is fine. Thank you!